# Kentico calling Functions Class

Tags: function, kentico

I have a class called Functions within App_Code and I am trying to call a method that returns a string. The problem I am having is that it doesn't seem to hit the breakpoint when I run the website.

This is the code that calls the method in the Functions class:

```
<div class="<%# SMEFunctions.GetContainerClasses()%> ">
```

And this is code within the class:

```
public static class SMEFunctions
{
    public static string GetContainerClasses()
    {
         ......
    }
}
```

When I view the page's source, it comes out as  instead of what I expect.

Comment: Where is your code? Inside of a transformation for a repeater, or in an .aspx file or?

Answer (score 1):

Use equals character in the inline ASP.NET markup as follows:

```
<div class="<%= SMEFunctions.GetContainerClasses()%> ">
```

instead of

```
<div class="<%# SMEFunctions.GetContainerClasses()%> ">
```

Answer (score 1):

When these two cases occur,

1. In page source code it is visible as <%# SMEFunctions.GetContainerClasses() %> and
2. It doesn't hit the breakpoint even though you have debug="true"

then it is most probably that you put the code inside a page template rather than a transformation. Changing "#" to "=" will do the trick.